# Inserting null values at the original array indices - sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, sorting

[StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sorting-qpecci?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I am sorting an array for an `*ngFor` on my Angular application. So far my array is being sorted on `sortId` value in ascending order. It then sorts the objects with `sordId: null` back into the array in its original indices position, result below:

```
Row 1 - Sort ID: null - original array position: 1
Row 2 - Sort ID: null - original array position: 2
Row 3 - Sort ID: null - original array position: 3
Row 4 - Sort ID: 1 - original array position: 8
Row 5 - Sort ID: null - original array position: 5
Row 6 - Sort ID: null - original array position: 6
Row 7 - Sort ID: 4 - original array position: 7
Row 8 - Sort ID: 5 - original array position: 4
```

.ts method

```
this.fieldsList = this.users
  .filter(x => x.sortId)
  .sort((a, b) => a.sortId - b.sortId);

this.users.forEach((x, i) => {
  if (x.sortId === null) this.fieldsList.splice(i, 0, x);
});
```

What I need it to do is for `sortID` to take priority over the null values. But the null values keep their original indice number/order unless there is a `sortId` that takes its place. So the example above will be the expected results below:

```
Row 1 - Sort ID: 1 - original array position: 8
Row 2 - Sort ID: null - original array position: 1
Row 3 - Sort ID: null - original array position: 2
Row 4 - Sort ID: 4 - original array position: 7
Row 5 - Sort ID: 5 - original array position: 4
Row 6 - Sort ID: null - original array position: 3
Row 7 - Sort ID: null - original array position: 4
Row 8 - Sort ID: null - original array position: 5
```

Comment: Do you want `Sort ID` to be equal to `index + 1` in the output? Like, `Sort ID: 1` is at index = 0, `Sort ID: 4` is at 3 etc.

Comment: sortID will be equal to index+1

Comment: What I need it to do is for sortID to take priority over the null values. But the null values keep their original indice number/order unless there is a sortId that takes its place.

Comment: null - 1?  the - is just a border in the row to signify another field

Comment: Your expected result has two "*original array position: 4*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job the way you wanted:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fieldsList = [...this.users];
    Array(this.fieldsList.length)
      .fill('1')
      .forEach((_, index) => {
        let user;
        let oldIndex;
        this.fieldsList.some((u, i) => {
          if(+u.sortId === index + 1) {
            user = u;
            oldIndex = i;
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        })
        const newIndex = +user?.sortId - 1;
        this.fieldsList.splice(newIndex, 0, user);
        this.fieldsList.splice(oldIndex + 1, 1);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a sorting algorithm. Your `sortId` simply specifies the index at which to place the item in the new array. Then fill up the rest with the null values. This can be done in linear time, without any `.sort()`.

```js
function reorder(items) {
  const result = new Array(items.length).fill(null);
  for (const item of items)
    if (item.sortId != null)
      result[item.sortId-1] = item;
  for (let i=0, j=0; i<result.length; i++) {
    if (result[i] == null) {
      while (items[j].sortId != null) j++
      result[i] = items[j++];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const users = [
  {
    arrayPosition: 1,
    sortId: null
  },
  {
    arrayPosition: 2,
    sortId: null
  },
  {
    arrayPosition: 3,
    sortId: null
  },
  {
    arrayPosition: 4,
    sortId: '5'
  },
  {
    arrayPosition: 5,
    sortId: null
  },
  {
    arrayPosition: 6,
    sortId: null
  },
  {
    arrayPosition: 7,
    sortId: '4'
  },
  {
    arrayPosition: 8,
    sortId: '1'
  }
];

for (const [index, user] of reorder(users).entries())
  console.log(`Row ${index+1} - Sort ID: ${user.sortId} - original array position: ${user.arrayPosition}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative using generators:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.fieldsList = [...this.generator(this.users)];
}

*generator(users: any[]) {
  const sorted = users
    .filter(x => x.sortId)
    .sort((a, b) => +a.sortId - +b.sortId);

  let j = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    if (users[i].sortId === null) {
      yield users[i];
    } else {
      yield sorted[j++];
    }
  }
}
```